# HP ProLiant DL360 iLO usage?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ilo

I have just purchased (from eBay) a HP ProLiant DL360 rack server for use as an additional domain controller on our network.

I noticed that it has a label on it with iLO Default Network Settings such as:

1. Server serial number
2. Username
3. DNS Name
4. Password

I am presuming this information is used in conjunction with the iLO ethernet port on the back of the server.

Is there any way I can use this? I am asking because from what I have read iLO allows users to control/view the server screen even when it's booting. So I could remotely reboot etc. using iLO.

As the server was bought from eBay - it was completely blank when I received it. I have installed Server 2008 Standard Edition, but nothing to do with iLO.

So, can I use iLO? Do I need to install anything on the server to make it work and how do I access the server remotely (via VPN) to use iLO?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you first turn the server on, there's a a section during startup that says "Push F8 to enter iLO Configuration" (might be some other function key). Do that and fill in the network information and setup a login.

Once that's done, open a web browser at your computer and enter the IP you configured. It should be very self explanatory from there.

The iLO configuration is not stored on disk, and not in the BIOS, so there's a decent chance it isn't clear. Also, how your VPN works and how to use it is completely outside the scope of using iLO.